# Javadoc generated for a class that does not exist

Tags: javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

The project consists of a root `pom.xml` that has several modules. *The root package `com.example` contains no code at all* (no `src` directory). The modules each contain one package, with subpackages, in typical maven structure: `com.example.foo`, `com.example.bar`, `com.example.bar.baz`, etc.

I have a [groups configuration](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/group-configuration.html) in my root `pom.xml`.

I am making javadocs with the command `mvn clean javadoc:aggregate`.

The resulting javadocs group the packages as expected, with one exception: I also get javadocs for the root package `com.example`, in a group *Other Packages*, and it contains one class, `App`, which has a comment of `Hello world!`. However, this `App` does not exist, in fact grepping through the entire codebase for `Hello world!` turns up zero results.

How do I avoid that docs for the not existing class is generated?

Already tried:

- `<excludePackageNames>com.example</excludePackageNames>` --> this results in no javadoc generated at all, because it also excludes subpackages.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

Add `<subpackages>com.example.foo:com.example.bar:com.example....<subpackages>` to the configuration, and omit the root package `com.example`.

This works as expected, but the downside is duplication of configuration.

I still welcome any answers that explain why and how that `App` javadoc is generated, out of intellectual curiosity.